# What are the real life examples of monotonic functions?

Tags: monotone-functions

Please tell me what are the real life examples of monotonic functions?  One example for increasing functions and one for the decreasing functions.

Comment: age over time :P

Comment: What about the age of the universe?

Comment: Your age is a monotonic increasing function in time. And the time left in your life is a monotonic decreasing function in time. @DanRust: Funny how we had the same example :D

Comment: @OP You really can't think of any?

Comment: I don't think there is a real life example. This is because infinity does not have a real-life equivalent, especially when you consider time as the variable. Does "universe" exist forever? Not sure. I am especially concerned about $-\infty$.

Comment: @msm  than what are the examples ? Other than real life

Comment: Numerous abstract examples such as $y=x$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A monotonic function doesn't have to have an infinite domain. It just need to be strictly increasing or decreasing over its domain.

Comment: Ok thanks all of you :)